# How to implement one_vs_all approach in pythonic way with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a sequence of labels, let it be [a,a,b,b,c,c]
I need to implement one-vs-all approach - return  amount of numpy arrays with labels, equal to amount of unique classes in binary representation, so:
class a -> `[1,1,0,0,0,0]`
class b -> `[0,0,1,1,0,0]`
class c -> `[0,0,0,0,1,1]`

in case I have two-classes labels' set such as `[a,b,a,a]`, I need just to return one numpy array like `[1,0,1,1]`. For this purpose I made the next func:

```
    def _preproc_labels(labels):
        class_names = [k for k in enumerate(set(labels))]
        if len(class_names)>2:
            one_vs_all_func = np.vectorize(lambda cls_name, x: 1 if 
                                           x==cls_name else 0)
            res = [one_vs_all_func(class_name[1], labels) for 
                                   class_name in class_names]
        elif len(class_names)==2:
            res = copy.deepcopy(labels)
            res[res==class_names[0][1]]=class_names[0][0]
            res[res==class_names[1][1]]=class_names[1][0]
            res = np.array([res])
        else:
            raise Exception('Labels are not valid!')
        return res, np.array(class_names)
```

However I would like to find more proper way to solve this task cos the current solution doesn't look fine and efficient. Also I need to save some pointers to find out what name of class is exactly represented by specific number (in my func it is `class_names`)

Comment: The indentation seems off, could you [edit] the code?

Comment: hope now its fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `numpy.unique`, to find the unique classes, and masks to find elements in the array matching the given class:

```
labels = np.array(['a','b','a','a','c','b'])
classes = np.unique(labels)
results = {}
for c in classes:
    # the mask will return an array of booleans so convert them to ints
    results[c] = (labels == c).astype(int)
```